# Chapter, sections, etc. in capital letters?

Tags: writing

Should I write "headers" like *chapter*, *section*, etc. with capital letters?

I think I have seen both; therefore I am not sure.

As an example, if I write something and want to refer to a specific chapter/section (they are numbered):

> "As we have seen in chapter/section [x]..."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a question for your editor, as there is no single convention. Whether and when to capitalize will be determined by the style guide in use, and for the sake of the reader, you should strive for consistency throughout the work.

[APA](http://www.sagepub.com/upm-data/27160_APA_Style.pdf), [for example](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/02/do-i-capitalize-this-word.html), says to use lowercase when referring to a chapter or section generically, but to capitalize when referring to a specific chapter or section, as you would a title:

> Additional details are provided in Chapter 4.
>
> Additional details are provided in the following chapter.

On the other hand, the [Chicago Manual](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Capitalization.html?page=1) and the [GPO](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008-5.pdf) (U.S. federal Government Printing Office) prefer that parts of a book be lowercase everywhere:

> A complete list is provided in appendix III.
>
> See section 7.

Comment: I much prefer APA's take on this. But you've done a great job with this answer.

Comment: It also depends on the dialect of English, I would suggest. Here in the United Kingdom, we use capitals less than in the USA, for example.